Acer Laptops still issues with Linux?
I'm thinking of buying an Acer notebook as it offers the best deal for the money, but in the past Acer has often caused problems with the bios etc. for inexperienced Linux users.
https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/EFI_Problembehebung/#Acer-Rechner
Chat-GPT claims that Acer is accommodating to Linux users on newer machines, but it's still a budget model (I'm dirt poor).
What is your experience?
Can you say anything about this model?
https://www.notebooksbilliger.de/acer+aspire+15+a15+41m+r4an+851447
I'm constantly messing up my Ubuntu system anyway.
On the one hand, it would be better to switch to Windows, on the other hand, since I want to learn descriptive statistics with Python and R, I could start right away with Ubuntu Command and teach myself.
But now I still have a Thinkpad E540, which I could use for Ubuntu, and the Acer for Windows.
I'm undecided...or I'll wait for a better deal.

Please refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll note "Shopping or Hardware Recommendations" are off-topic.  Ubuntu Forums allows those sort of opinion based questions.
